# CSS border color issue

Tags: css

I am trying to put a red border of 1px and I have a problem. The top and bottom of the border are red, but not the left and right.

If I change the color, pink for example, the issue disappears.

Any idea?

```css
div.red-border {
 border: solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
   <div class="red-border">
<p>Hi!</p>
<p> I'm trying to put a red border</p>
   </div>
```

Comment: Here border is full red! Can you check?

Comment: Check whether your page is zoomed at 100%. Hit `Ctrl` + `0` to reset the zoom.

Comment: The color is red. check again.

Comment: The color is red but not the same red and zoom does not affect the result. Could it be the monitor?

Answer (score 0):

Checking Firefox Quantum your border works, and you are using the shorthand for border styling, but in a different order. I think this order is better, [so does the MDN site covering the CSS spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Shorthand_properties#Border_Properties), and more common:

```
1px solid red
```

```css
div.red-border {
 border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="red-border">
<p>Hi!</p>
<p> I'm trying to put a red border</p>
   </div>
```